# jQuery nextAll after certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table as following, And wanted to get all `parent_tr` after `display-order="-1"`

```
 <table>
     <thead>...</thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr class='parent_tr'><td></td>....<td></td></tr> //no of `td`s in each row
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr class='parent_tr'><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr class='parent_tr' display-order="-1"><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr class='parent_tr'><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr class='parent_tr'><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td>....<td></td></tr>
        .
        .
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Here is my JavaScript(jQuery) what I'm trying:

```
   $(".parent_tr[display-order!='-1']").nextAll(".parent_tr");  
  //Console output - [<tr class=​"parent_tr">​…​</tr>, <tr class=​"parent_tr">​…​</tr>, <tr class=​"parent_tr" display-order=​"-1">​…​</tr>​, <tr class=​"parent_tr">​…​</tr>​, <tr class=​"parent_tr">​…​</tr>,..]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have incorrect selector. you need to use **[attribute equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**:

```
$(".parent_tr[display-order='-1']").nextAll(".parent_tr");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dg5gLcpo/)**

Answer (score 2):

Your condition checking is wrong and you have to use `=` instead of `!=` in your case.

```
$(".parent_tr[display-order='-1']").nextAll(".parent_tr");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvxyupe9/1/)**